# How to find ip address of computer connected to domain controller (on login)

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain, domain-controller

Every time the user login to domain i need to run script and send his computer ip to my linux mashine. I already have sending script but i need to pass ip as parameter. Is it possible to get this ip in some way ?

Comment: Wouldn't their DNS entry be sufficient if you setup DHCP and DNS correctly?

Comment: I coded a short C# app for this and used `Dns.GetHostName();`, but ETL's answer should work for batch.

Comment: unfortunatelly i have static ip assigned on all computers. After user log into domain i want to grab his ip send it to my firewall and there i add this ip to allowed to connect to internet.

Comment: so if it is impossible - how to get cn and ou of logged user using script.bat run on logon ?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it on something similar - one works for WinXP the other for Win7.

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%f in ('ipconfig ^| findstr /c:"IPv4 Address"') do (
        set ip_address=%%f
        goto next
)

for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%f in ('ipconfig ^| findstr /c:"IP Address"') do (
        set ip_address=%%f
        goto next
)

:next
echo IP Address %ip_address%
```

Comment: how do you run it ? i save it in ip.bat and run but it did not work.

Comment: what did not work?

Comment: i have to change it little bit because i have not english windows so the ipconfig looks diffirent :)

Comment: @Kriss - ah well yes, that would be a problem.

Comment: If i add this script to login scripts in active directory user profile  on what side it will be executed - server or user maschine ? I am afraid that it will be server side so i get server ip not user.

Comment: @Kriss - user machine. Windows is mostly client side programs. Group policies are applied by the client machine, etc. Not on the Domain Controller.